# ¿Cómo insertar un dato de llave foranea en mysql desde un form en html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo este form en donde registro a un paciente con los siguientes datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando le doy guardar me recarga la pagina como si hubiera hecho el insert, el problema es que no lo hace o al menos no me aparece en la base de datos

Este es mi controlador

```
//Crear un nuevo registro
    public function new($data)
    {
        $this->db();
        try{
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO paciente (nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido,curp,rfc,nacimiento,telefono,direccion,codigo_postal,id_genero,id_tratamiento,id_consultorio) 
            VALUES (:nombre, :primer_apellido, :segundo_apellido,:curp,:rfc,:nacimiento,:telefono,:direccion,:codigo_postal,:id_genero,:id_tratamiento,:id_consultorio)";
            $st = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $st->bindParam(":nombre", $data['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":primer_apellido", $data['primer_apellido'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":segundo_apellido", $data['segundo_apellido'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":curp", $data['curp'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":rfc", $data['rfc'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":nacimiento", $data['nacimiento'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":telefono", $data['telefono'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":direccion", $data['direccion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":codigo_postal", $data['codigo_postal'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $st->bindParam(":id_genero", $data['id_genero'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $st->bindParam(":id_tratamiento", $data['id_tratamiento'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $st->bindParam(":id_consultorio", $data['id_consultorio'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $st->execute();
            $rc = $st->rowCount();
        }catch(PDOException $Exception){
            $rc = 0;
            print "DBA FAIL:" . $Exception->getMessage();
            $this->db->rollBack();
        }
        
        return $rc;
    }
```

Este es mi formulario

```
<h1>
    <?php echo ($action == 'edit') ? 'Modificar' : 'Nuevo'; ?> Paciente
</h1>

<form class="container-fluid" method="POST" action="paciente.php?action=<?php echo ($action); ?>"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="text" class="" id="nombre" name="data[nombre]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['nombre']) ? $data[0]['nombre'] : ''; ?>" minlength="3"
                maxlength="200">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <label for="primer_apellido">Apellido Paterno</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="text" class="" id="primer_apellido" name="data[primer_apellido]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['primer_apellido']) ? $data[0]['primer_apellido'] : ''; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <label for="segundo_apellido">Apellido Materno</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="text" class="" id="segundo_apellido" name="data[segundo_apellido]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['segundo_apellido']) ? $data[0]['segundo_apellido'] : ''; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="curp">Curp</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="text" class="" id="curp" name="data[curp]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['curp']) ? $data[0]['curp'] : ''; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="rfc">RFC</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="text" class="" id="rfc" name="data[rfc]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['rfc']) ? $data[0]['rfc'] : ''; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="nacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="date" class="" id="nacimiento" name="data[nacimiento]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['nacimiento']) ? $data[0]['nacimiento'] : ''; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="text" class="" id="telefono" name="data[telefono]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['telefono']) ? $data[0]['telefono'] : ''; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="text" class="" id="direccion" name="data[direccion]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['direccion']) ? $data[0]['direccion'] : ''; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="codigo_postal">Codigo Postal</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-2">
            <input required="required" type="text" class="" id="codigo_postal" name="data[codigo_postal]"
                value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['codigo_postal']) ? $data[0]['codigo_postal'] : ''; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="id_genero">Genero:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <select name="data[id_genero]" required="required">
                <?php
                $selected = " ";
                foreach ($dataGenero as $key => $genero):
                    if ($genero['id_genero'] == $data[0]['id_genero']):
                        $selected = "selected";
                    endif;
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $genero['id_genero']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>
                        <?php echo $genero['genero'] ?></option>
                    <?php $selected = " "; endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="id_tratamiento">Tratamiento:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <select name="data[id_tratamiento]" required="required">
                <?php
                $selected = " ";
                foreach ($dataTratamiento as $key => $tratamiento):
                    if ($tratamiento['id_tratamiento'] == $data[0]['id_tratamiento']):
                        $selected = "selected";
                    endif;
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $tratamiento['id_tratamiento']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>
                        <?php echo $tratamiento['tratamiento'] ?></option>
                    <?php $selected = " "; endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div> 
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
            <label for="id_consultorio">Consultorio:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <select name="data[id_consultorio]" required="required">
                <?php
                $selected = " ";
                foreach ($dataConsultorio as $key => $consultorio):
                    if ($consultorio['id_consultorio'] == $data[0]['id_consultorio']):
                        $selected = "selected";
                    endif;
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $consultorio['id_consultorio']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>
                        <?php echo $consultorio['consultorio'] ?></option>
                    <?php $selected = " "; endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div> 

<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" name="enviar" value="Guardar">
        </div>
    </div>

    <?
    if ($action == 'edit'): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="data[id_paciente]"
            value="<?php echo isset($data[0]['id_paciente']) ? $data[0]['id_paciente'] : ''; ?>" class="" />
    <? endif; ?>
</form>
```

Y este es mi enrutador

```
case 'new':
        $dataGenero = $genero->get(null);
        $dataTratamiento = $tratamiento->get(null);
        $dataConsultorio = $consultorio->get(null);
        if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
            $data = $_POST['data'];
            $cantidad = $paciente->new($data);
            if ($cantidad) {
         //       $paciente->flash('success', 'Registro dado de alta con éxito');
                $data = $paciente->get(null);
                include('view/paciente/index.php');
            } else {
                
                //$proyecto->flash('danger', 'Algo fallo');
                include('view/paciente/form.php');
            }
        } else {
            include('view/paciente/form.php');
        }
        break;
```

Sospecho que el error esta en el form de el genero, tratamiento y consultorio pero no estoy seguro, además de que estas ultimas 3 opciones son llaves foráneas no nulas. Las cambie a nulas y me seguia haciendo lo mismo el programa. ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Yo cambiaría en tu enrutador `if ($cantidad)` por `if ($cantidad !== 0)` y en el controlador `$rc = $st->rowCount();` por `$rc = $st->affectedRows`

Comment: Lo hice y no me funciono

Comment: Edité el comentario después de tu prueba

Comment: No me detecta lo que me propusiste en el controlador y me da un error PHP

Answer (score 0):

El error esta al momento de abrir una transacción y no terminarla de ejecutar.
`$rc = $st->rowCount();`

Debajo de esta linea se hace el commit para ejecutar la transaccion con la siguiente linea `$this->db->commit();`